# TTaskbar incompatibility?

Tags: delphi, taskbar, delphi-xe8

In a normal Delphi XE8 VCL Form application, after having put a `TTaskbar` component on the form, at program start always the following error message box is displayed TWICE:

[image]

There are NO OTHER components on the form, so I suppose it is an internal incompatibility.

I do nothing with the TTaskbar component in this test project, it has just been put on the form.

The strange thing is: It worked without error message at program start for about one day. Now always this error message is displayed at program start, even in a new VCL Form project with no other components.

What could be the cause for this error? Could it be a bug in the component?

**EDIT**: Now this is very strange: When I create the Taskbar component **at run-time** in a button-click event, then NO error message is displayed and the TTaskbar properties work well:

```
var
  Taskbar1: TTaskbar;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Taskbar1 := TTaskbar.Create(Self);

  with Taskbar1 do
  begin
    Name := 'Taskbar1';
    //TaskBarButtons := <>; // ??
    TabProperties := [];
    ProgressState := TTaskBarProgressState.Normal;
    ProgressMaxValue := 5;
    ProgressValue := 2; // works well
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT2**: Even more strange: When instead of creating the TTaskbar object in the button-click event I create it in the `FormCreate` event then 3 error messages are displayed:

var
    Taskbar1: TTaskbar;

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Taskbar1 := TTaskbar.Create(Self);

  with Taskbar1 do
  begin
    Name := 'Taskbar1';
    //TaskBarButtons := <>; // ??
    TabProperties := [];
  end;
end;
```

This is the first error message displayed while the form is still not visible:

[image]

The other two error messages are the same as the first screenshot above and are displayed when the form has become visible.

Comment: `TTaskBar` has a LOT of bugs and design flaws in it.  I **strongly** suggest you NOT use it at all, use `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList)` to access the `ITaskbarList...` interfaces directly instead.

Comment: Yes, that component is just rubbish. Don't use it. It's not as though the COM interface is hard to use.

Comment: FWIW: There are other wrappers like https://github.com/chaosben/theunknownones/wiki/TaskbarListComponents. NB: I've never really used that.

Comment: Does this imply the recommendation to not trust components from Embarcadero? How would you rate the overall quality of components from Embarcadero?

Comment: @user It varies. Treat each case on its own merits. This component is clearly rubbish. Others work fine. My guess is that there is a link between how recently it was added. The recent additions being, on average, lower quality than older components. I think the quality of Emba's VCL devs has dropped.

Comment: To add, just the existence of a `TTaskbar` is causing a very nasty issue when the user decides to click on the "Show Desktop" button in the bottom-right corner of the screen. When the user then proceeds to restore the minimized application, it instead shows that ugly little "minimized" box in the bottom-left corner of the screen from Windows 3.1, and the user has to double-click that box to restore the application. Once I got rid of the `TTaskbar`, all worked fine.